# remove nested subscribe switchMap or MergeMap

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have removed all nested subscriptions, but I think my solution is not optimized, and if it's better to use mergeMap instead of switchMap? this code is about getting query params from URLs and sending them to the service for filter results.it works without any error, I just need advice if it's clean code or is ugly.  Any help or advice would be great

```
ngOnInit() {
    const params$ = this.route.params;
    const queryParams$ = this.route.queryParams;
    
    params$
      .pipe(
        combineLatestWith(queryParams$),
        switchMap(([params, queryParams]) => {
          const query = {};
          const operationsObservables = [];

          if (params['pages']) {
              query['limite'] = (+params['pages'] - 1) * 10;
            this.limite = +params['pages'] - 1;
          }
          Object.keys(queryParams).map(k => {
            switch (k) {
              case 'clientIds':
                 query['clientIds'] = queryParams['clientIds'].split(',');
                 operationsObservables.push(
                     this.clientService.getUserList({ clientIds: query['clientIds'] }).pipe(
                      map(result => {
                      this.searchedUsers = result.data.list
                    }),
                      catchError(error => {
                        this.handleErrors.handleErrors(error);
                        return EMPTY;
                    }),
                  ),
                );
                break;
              case 'type':
                query[k] = queryParams[k];
                break;
            }
          });
          return this.clientService.update
            .pipe(
              startWith(null),
              switchMap(() => {
                return this.loggingService.getAdminLoggingList(query).pipe(
                  map(response => {
                    this.loggings.next(response.data);
                    return EMPTY;
                  }),
                  catchError(err => {
                    this.handleErrors.handleErrors(err);
                    return EMPTY;
                  }),
                );
              }),
            )
            .pipe(combineLatestWith(operationsObservables));
        }),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribeSubject),
      )
      .subscribe(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want my honest opinion, this code looks kind of messy. Main reason is that your pipes are not pure. You are setting variables from inside your pipe operators in an imperative way. Can you try to think about what your reactive sources are (like `route.params` and `route.queryParams`) and what your sinks will be?

A few things to consider:

1.

```
params$
      .pipe(
        combineLatestWith(queryParams$)
```

can be replaced with:

```
combineLatest([params$, queryParams$]
```

which will, in this case, have the same result. ActivatedRoute will fire both on routing event.

2. Try to extract complex logic like `Object.keys(queryParams).map(k => {...}` into a separate typed function, which naming makes clear what the function is about.
3. If your sinks are clearly defined observables, you will not need `takeUntil` and `subscribe` anymore. All values needed can be extracted in your template using `async` pipe, which will handle unsubscription automatically.
4. Try to avoid setting things like `this.exampleVariable` from inside pipes. The only output a pipe should have is the observable, that pops out at the end of it. If several variables should be set within a pipe, it's a good idea to define separate pipes for it.
5. You should assign types to your objects, even if they are plain objects or arrays in the beginning. This helps to prevent errors and also makes it easier to understand your code without having to look at all different places.
6. I still don't understand what exactly your assignment of `this.searchedUsers=...` is doing. You are also performing this assignment in a for loop where observables are created. I guess the variable would always be directly overwritten, which should in theory result in many rerenderings.
7. Your last call to `.pipe(combineLatestWith(operationsObservables));` seems to only be relevant, since you need a subscription to the array of observables. The logic is defined on top imperatively, which also spreads logic around. Here you should also focus on what your actual data sink (the data you want to consume) should be.